# How can I reject all non-latin letters and numbers, but allow latin numbers and letters and special characters using regular expression?

Tags: regex

Was looking for a way to allow all Latin numbers and letters [a-zA-Z0-9], all special characters [~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|:;"'<,>.?/], and reject anything else.

I understand how to allow all the Latin numbers and letters and special characters, it's the rejection of anything else that I am looking help for.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score -1):

If you understand how to allow all the latin numbers,letters and special characters then it will reject anything too. you can use all of the characters in range.

```
(?i)[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|:;"'<,>.?\/]
```

Or if you use \S+ it will accept all characters except space.